# How can I call data in a pandas DataFrame according to lower and upper bound?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an easier way to write the following?
`DataFrame2` should include all rows from `DataFrame` which have a value in the `Age` column between 10 and 40.

```
DataFrame2=DataFrame[DataFrame['Age']<40]
DataFrame2=DataFrame2[DataFrame2['Age']>10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have numexpr installed, you can use [`query()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
DataFrame2 = DataFrame.query('Age < 40 & Age > 10')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use &:

```
df2 = df[(10 < df['Age']) & (df['Age'] < 40)]
```

*Note: query/numexp will be more efficient as it won't create as many temporary arrays.*